# batch file for copying folders and files into multiple directories as specied times

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

A batch file for...

Display:
Enter the site name: e.g. web or test (the path should be associated with them i.e. c:/inetpub/test  or c:/inetpub/website )

Enter number of copies you want.. e.g. 20 (max 100)

function:
it will copying one directory(as the name specified test or website) to another with sub folders and files (in multiple folders) as specified times..
with folder name 1..2..3..4..5..6......99..100(path e.g. c:/inetpub/wwwroot/test/1 and /2 and /3...c:/inetpub/wwwroot/test/100)

*And adding sites into iis as specified times ...

Comment: i have tried to copy those folders to some destination and adding sites to iis.. in separate batch file

Comment: as I imagine, it is just a loop of copy command with dynamic source and destination path, isn't it?

Comment: yes.. and one more thing,those files are associated with input number..i.e between 1 to 100.. and foldername i.e. test or website... ...in simple what folder we want to copy, where and how many times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insufficient data about home directory and destiny directory, make some changes if needed:

```
@Echo OFF

:Name_menu
Set /P "Name=Enter the site name >>"
IF NOT DEFINED NAME (Set "Name=" & GOTO:Name_menu)

:Rounds_menu
Set /P "Rounds=Enter number of copies you want (Max 100)>>"
IF NOT DEFINED ROUNDS (Set "Rounds=Name" & GOTO:Rounds_menu)
If %ROUNDS% GTR 99    (Set "Rounds="     & GOTO:Rounds_menu)


:: I've assumed:
:: home dir is the script's dir
:: a folder with the name of the gived website name exists in home dir.
:: you want destiny dir to be "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" 
FOR /L %%# in (0,1,%ROUNDS%) DO (
MKDIR "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\%NAME%\%%#" >NUL
XCOPY /E /Y ".\%NAME%\*" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\%NAME%\%%#\"
)

:: About "And adding sites into iis as specified times ..."
:: I don't know IIS and what you want, sorry.

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: hello, see this line" XCOPY /E /Y ".\%NAME%\*" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\%NAME%\%%#\"" than means: "XCOPY /E /Y "CurrentDir\website_name_folder\ALL(ALL Folders, subfolders and files)" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\website_name_folder\number\"  Are you sure don't copy files? maybe I've do a typo, tell me more about the problem.

Comment: Actually all is done with ur script..i have manually added that folders' path.. ...Instead of XCOPY /E /Y ".\%NAME%\*" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\%NAME%\%%#\"  i have used XCOPY /E /Y "mypath\%NAME%\*" "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\%NAME%\%%#\".. that worked for me...And about IIS is the microsofts' web server ...thanks for your valuable time and help..saved my time... :)